# What insect/bug species do these belong to?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I randomly saw what I thought was dust on the counter in my bathroom (NYC Apartment - higher apartment, >10 floors up) this afternoon (June 1st) ... but when I got closer observed that they were little bugs! They were stuck to the counter likely because I had spilled some oil on there and they were unable to get out of there and died on the surface (thankfully). I haven't seen these anywhere else in the apartment or bathroom.

What are these? Are these dangerous or a cause to be concerned? Are there likely more of these elsewhere? Any recommendations for their removal?

[[image: In Bathroom][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBGNs.jpg)

[image: White Background]

[image: White Background with Dime for Size Reference]